# Remote connection to postgreSQL server in google cloud VM instance

Tags: postgresql, google-app-engine, google-compute-engine, remote-connection

I can't get remote access to my PostgreSQL server in Ubuntu16.04 VM instance in google cloud from my laptop. I've added my laptop IP to pg_hba.conf in Google Cloud and tried both "md5" and "Trust" methods:

`#IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             [mylocalIP]/32          md5`

Furthermore I've tried both * and [mylocalIP] in postgresql.conf:

```
# - Connection Settings 
listen_addresses = '*'      # what IP address(es) to listen on;
```

In google cloud firewall i've following setup

```
default-allow-http  http-server     IP ranges: 0.0.0.0/0    tcp:80  Allow   1000    default
default-allow-https https-server    IP ranges: 0.0.0.0/0    tcp:443 Allow   1000    default
default-allow-psql  Apply to all    IP ranges: 0.0.0.0/0    tcp:5432Allow   1000    default
Laptop              Apply to all    IP ranges: [mylocalIP]/32   all     Allow   1000    default
```

Also I can putty to my Google Cloud VM instance with SSH key, so I can have some remote connection.

I think this is Google Cloud firewall issue cause I can use remote connection to my postgreSQL server in my local VM (win 2012 server) with following setup without problems.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In your pg_hba.conf file, try adding the line

```
host    all             all           0.0.0.0/0         md5
```

Your firewall rules appear to be correct. You only need the rule `tcp:5432` for ip ranges `0.0.0.0/0`

Comment: "try adding the line" - why is this line added?

Comment: This line means allow all users to connect to all databases from any IP address, and they must provide an MD5-encrypted password for authentication.